# First install, Nvidia GeForce 4 4200, GPU lockup

Tags: nvidia, software-installation

I used my Wintel box to download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Burned an install DVD and installed on my laptop (Dell Inspiron 8500). When I try to boot the laptop from the hard drive I get a GPU Lockup message. If I let it sit, after a few minutes I get messages about a channel failing to idle. These repeat every few minutes. I have read some other posts and it sounds like I still ought to be able to do something, but I have no idea what. My GPU is an Nvida GeForce 4 4200. I am a total newbie at Linux. I have mark Sobell's Practical Guide to Ubuntu Linux. I will search it as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you boot ubuntu from a livecd right after the bios splash screen you will get a purple screen with a keyboard logo at the bottom. Press any key at that moment to access a menu. Select your language with the arrow keys, press enter and you will see a menu. If you press the F6 key, a menu at the bottom will open allowing you to set kernel options with the space bar or enter key. Pick the option NOMODESET. You can close the menu with escape key and resume booting by selecting the option “try ubuntu without installing” (please note that session does allow you to install ubuntu once you found the kernel options cured your problem).

Comment: [How to set NOMODESET and other kernel boot options in grub2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132)